# Is mumble safe (privacy wise)?

Tags: privacy, mumble

When chatting on IRC, it is possible to leak data like OS, CPU type if the IRC client happens to leak it in VERSION string. Anybody doing /CTCP VERSION can see it. Same about timezone (/CTCP TIME). This can be mitigated by turning replies to CTCP queries off. Also, IP address is leaked to others (**/whois nickname** will show it if it's not cloaked).

By analogy, does the mumble client expose such sensitive data to others that are connected to the same server? If it does, what are the ways to mitigate this?

Comment: To clarify are you talking about http://www.mumble.com/ ? And if YES, are you asking about the server or the downloadable mumble client?

Comment: I am asking about the mumble voice chat client. Will edit my question to make it clear.

Comment: FYI, mumble.com is a commercial service providing hosting for the Mumble VoIP software. This open-source software can be found on SourceForge : http://mumble.sourceforge.net/ .

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](http://forums.mumble.info/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=508&p=2083) on their developer technical forum. Yes Murmur does send info like operating system and version info.

Here is a [list of configuration options](http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Murmur.ini) for murmur and the [source code on github](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble)

Add this line to your murmur.ini to stop sending OS version info.

`sendversion=False`

Add this line to obfuscate your IP

`obfuscate=true`

You can disable allowing pings

`allowping=false`

Disable logging which is accessible via RPC

`logdays=-1`

If you run this under linux or mac, do not run it has root or a super user, but if you have to use the `uname` config option

I could not find anything about timezone.

The only EULA and privacy document I found is the one on their order page, linked in the section about having to agree to their 'Services Agreement'. Second place I found some privacy  info was on their [wiki](http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Main_Page)

Comment: Murmur is the server, not the client, I am concerned about the client. In a [me - mumble server - you] scenario, generally there's no way for you to sniff and find my IP. While mumble is indeed used in online games, my question isn't asked in this context, it's strictly about the mumble client and private data it may eventually leak.

Comment: I would ask your question in their technical forum. You can also check out the source code if you are so inclined https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble

Comment: "on their order page" - I think you are confusing a specific hoster with the Mumble project and software. The project _has no order page_.

Answer (score 0):

Mumble is safe. From what you listed, only the OS gets shared with people with elevated permissions on the server.

Data exposed to other users is primarily what you see (username, user comment), your identification (user certificate) if you use one, and technical information for protocol negotiation (selecting a compatible audio codec between clients; Opus, or CELT 0.7 baseline).

Only moderators/admins on servers with elevated permissions can see additional information - namely your OS. You can see the shared information (mostly technical) in the user information dialog by right-clicking yourself and opening *Information*.

[image]